# How can i loop database items in flutter firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, loops, dart

I'm trying to build and Q&A app.
In my questions page i'm building my answers from a method.
This is the method ;

```
 SizedBox buildAnswerBox(var questionsOfSports,int answers) {
    String? answerT;
    return SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      width: 350,
      child: StreamBuilder(stream: questionsOfSports.snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncsnapshot) {
          List<dynamic> question1 = asyncsnapshot.data.data()['q1']['q1Answers'];
          switch (answers) {
            case 1 :{ answerT=question1[0];}
          break;
            case 2 : {answerT=question1[1];}
          break;
            case 3 : {answerT=question1[2];}
          break;
            case 4 : {answerT=question1[3];}
          }

          return TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('$answerT'),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            ),
          );
        },),
    );
```

String answerT holding arguments coming from statefull widget

```
buildAnswerBox(questionsOfSports,4),
```

Now i want to loop my data for every question and those's question's answers but i don't know how .

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what type `questionsOfSports` is, but assuming it is a stream of some type T, you don't need to add the `.snapshots()` when referring to the stream in your `StreamBuilder`.

If `questionsOfSports` is a list, then you need to convert that list into a stream (see [here](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams)).

All that said, it is not obvious to me that a Stream/StreamBuilder to create this widget is the best way to do this - it may be simpler and easier to just loop over a list of questions/answers and create a new widget every time a button is pressed.

Comment: i need an example for last thing u say, im new at it and only way i know streambuilder